# Does Cloudbees (hosted) Jenkins support building .NET products?

Tags: .net, jenkins, cloudbees

Our product consists of multiple deliverables: Java Server war(s)/client jar, cross-platform C/C++ (windows, linux, embedded), .NET, iOS and Android.

Can we use hosted Cloudbees Jenkins CI (i.e. DEV@Cloud) functionality to build .NET and Windows-based C/C++ deliverables which require a Windows OS?  If not, how do customers use DEV@Cloud when they have Windows-based build requirements?

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 0):

iOS applications can be built using a Mac OS X slave provided by CloudBees.

Currently there are no Windows cloud slaves for building things like Win32 C++ application (or simply running tests on Windows), so your usual option is to use [On-Premise Executors](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/On-Premise+Executors) with your own Windows build slaves.

Another option is to use [EC2 Executors](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/EC2+Executors). Similarly to on-premise executors, you are then responsible for supplying your own slaves; but you need not worry about purchasing and maintaing your own hardware, and you can scale up your system quickly if load increases.